# Extracting a particular string value from a specific string

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a string and I want to extract a particular string from the given string using a **regular expression**. I tried with the help of *string split*. But that takes a lot of processing to achieve the answer. The string to be extracted is `emr_cluster`:

```
var str = "edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;html=1;exitX=0.915;exitY=0.5;exitPerimeter=0;entryX=0;entryY=0.5;entryPerimeter=0;jettySize=auto;orthogonalLoop=1;outlineConnect=0;dashed=0;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;verticalAlign=top;align=center;html=1;shape=mxgraph.aws3.emr_cluster;fillColor=#F58534;gradientColor=none;";
```

How can I extract `emr_cluster` and get the value?

Comment: How do you what is the string that is supposed to be extracted?

Comment: So, do you want to get "shape" parameter value? Like "mxgraph.aws3.emr_cluster"?

Comment: How about doing `.split("")` then you can use any method to iterate on the newly created array like `.map` then you can check each letter and the following one.
You can also chunk the array elements into groups of 11 charachters so that you can iterate over that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
var str = "edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;html=1;exitX=0.915;exitY=0.5;exitPerimeter=0;entryX=0;entryY=0.5;entryPerimeter=0;jettySize=auto;orthogonalLoop=1;outlineConnect=0;dashed=0;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;verticalAlign=top;align=center;html=1;shape=mxgraph.aws3.emr_cluster;fillColor=#F58534;gradientColor=none;";
let out = str.match(/shape=.*\..*\.(.*?);/)[1];
console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is the shape that is the intended string and the source of that shape is always sourced from "mxgraph.aws3." - then you can split it on that - and then split on the next ";" character to get the shape value you are after.

```js
var str = "edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;html=1;exitX=0.915;exitY=0.5;exitPerimeter=0;entryX=0;entryY=0.5;entryPerimeter=0;jettySize=auto;orthogonalLoop=1;outlineConnect=0;dashed=0;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;verticalAlign=top;align=center;html=1;shape=mxgraph.aws3.emr_cluster;fillColor=#F58534;gradientColor=none;";

var shape = str.split('mxgraph.aws3.')[1].split(';')[0];

console.log(shape) // gives "emr_cluster"
```

if it is a differennt source - then you can so the same - burt split on the "shape=" to get the full source of the shape property.

```js
var str = "edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;html=1;exitX=0.915;exitY=0.5;exitPerimeter=0;entryX=0;entryY=0.5;entryPerimeter=0;jettySize=auto;orthogonalLoop=1;outlineConnect=0;dashed=0;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;verticalAlign=top;align=center;html=1;shape=mxgraph.aws3.emr_cluster;fillColor=#F58534;gradientColor=none;";

var shape = str.split('shape=')[1].split(';')[0];

console.log(shape) // gives "mxgraph.aws3.emr_cluster"
```